# How to join three tables that linked to one table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I join three tables that are all linked to one table?

For example, I need to join a term table, a student table and a course table in a University db. 
All these tables are linked to just the section table and none other table, but I need to retrieve data from all three tables.

Comment: can we get the column details of the tables

Comment: Imagine the db design would be a bad one and two of the tables would actually be one - how would you go about ? What would you do if three tables were folded in one?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The section table has a student_id column as a foreign key to the student table, a course_id column being the relative key to the course table, and the term_id column which is the primary key in the term table and the foreign key in the section table. These other 3 tables are not in any way linked to each other, except through the section table. I need to count number of credits from the course table the a student takes (student table) per term (term table)

Answer (score 2):

You will have a key relationship between these tables.

**ex:** you will have a *courseid* in *Course* table and the same as a foreign key reference in *Student* table.

You should decide on what type of join(INNER, OUTER) you need.

From your requirement:

You need sum of the number of credits selected for each term by students. For this you can use the below query.

```
select selection.student_id, selection.course_id, selection.term_id, sum(course.credits) from selection 
join student on selection.student_id = student.id
join course on selection.course_id = course.id
join term on selection.term_id = term.id
group by selection.student_id, selection.course_id, selection.term_id
```

Comment: Thanks Andrews, I think this is about what I want. This covers it. I didn't know you could link to a table that has been linked to a different table in the same query.

Comment: glad it solves your problem. Also accept this answer as accepted to approve the same @S.C.A.N